# Can't print from Photoshop... Bad %%BoundingBox: comment seen!

Tags: macos, adobe-photoshop, printing

Trying to print from Adobe Photoshop CS4 results in "Bad %%BoundingBox: comment seen!", and the job doesn't print. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Canon iR C3380 printer,
MacBook Pro,
OS X version 10.6.4

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround you can try "print previewing" the document first via the OS X print box.

You could also try reinstalling the printer driver. A quick Google reveals that this is a common issue that is mostly unresolved, and may be a Postscript issue.